# Remember Selectbox value after form is submitted with error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

Right now if i submit my form and there is an error it just shows there is an error, without reselecting the project there was an error for, (the page is called "change project") here u can change the values for a certain project.

P.S. in the picture i posted u can see i specifically entered a string 'test' where there should be an integer.

I tried $("#editProjectSelect").val($('#hidden-input').val());; but it didn't work

```
     <div id="project-wijzigen" class="form">
        <h2> Wijzig een project </h2>       

        <select id="editprojectSelect" name="editprojectSelect" onchange="getDetails()">
        <option value="">-</option>
        </select>
        <?php echo '<input type="hidden" id="hidden-input" value="'.$_POST['editProjectSelect'].'">';?>
        <div id="editProject">
            <?php echo form_open('c_admin/wijzigProject');?>
                <h2 id="hoofding"></h2>
                <div><label> Project titel: </label> <input type="text" id="pt" name="titel" required value="<?php echo set_value('projecttitel'); ?>"/></div>
                <div><label> Startdatum: </label> <input type="text" id="sd" name="start" required value="<?php echo set_value('startdatum'); ?>"/></div>
                <div><label> Einddatum: </label> <input type="text" id="ed" name="eind" required value="<?php echo set_value('einddatum'); ?>"/></div>
                <div><label> In samenwerking met: </label> <input type="text" id="samen" name="samen" required value="<?php echo set_value('ism'); ?>"/></div>
                <div><label> Omschrijving: </label> <textarea id="omschr" name="text" required value="<?php echo set_value('text'); ?>"></textarea></div>
                <input type="hidden" id="hiddenID" name="hiddenID" />

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Wijzig project"/>

            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>

     <?php      

// --------------------------- Error checking/display           
            if(isset($projectWijzigenError)) // check of de variabele wel een waarde heeft (als je die zomaar oproept en hij moest leeg of NULL zijn dan krijg je een error op je pagina)
                {
                if ($projectWijzigenError=='true') // ALS er een error is, dan opent de form terug en worden errors weergegeven
                {
?>
                    <script>
                    $("#editProjectSelect").val($('#hidden-input').val());
                    $('#project-wijzigen').show();
                    $(this).toggleClass('close');
                    </script>

<?php 
                echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); 
                }  
                }
// -------------------------- End error checking/displaying             
?>

    </div>


function getDetails()
{   
    //$("#editProject").empty();
    document.getElementById('editProject').style.display = "none";
    $(".error").empty();
    var sel = document.getElementById('editprojectSelect');
    var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
    var p = opt.value;

    if(p != "")
    {
        document.getElementById('editProject').style.display = "block";
        //$("#editProject").append($("<label></label><br />").html("test"));
        $.ajax(
        {
        url:"<?php echo site_url("c_admin/ajaxProject");?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {project: p},
        success: function(msg)
            {                       
                var jsonMsg = $.parseJSON(msg);

                $('#hoofding').html(jsonMsg.Projecttitel);
                document.getElementById("pt").value = jsonMsg.Projecttitel;
                document.getElementById("sd").value = jsonMsg.Startdatum;
                document.getElementById("ed").value = jsonMsg.Einddatum;
                document.getElementById("samen").value = jsonMsg.ISM;
                document.getElementById("omschr").value = jsonMsg.Projecttekst;
                document.getElementById("hiddenID").value = jsonMsg.ProjectID;

            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In the code there is no any `option` tag with the text - `test 02...`. Where are you populating the `select` menu?

Comment: Added the code with an edit.